# Forcing jQuery UI dialog button focus

Tags: jquery-ui, button, dialog

I have several  jQueryUI dialogs with `Ok` and `Cancel` and radio buttons (no text input).

My requirements are:

OK button should be right of the Cancel button and Ok button should be in focus:

1. when the dialog opens,

   after any user click or drag.

Requirement no 1 can be implemented by giving the Ok button an id and the following code:
`open: function(event, ui) {
   $('#OkButton').focus();
},`

Requirement no 2 is harder. It could be implemented by defining focusing delegates for a lot of events:

- .ui-dialog-titlebar click

  .ui-dialog-buttonpane click

  dragStop

  etc

But surely there must be a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. `myDialog` is main dialog `div` When you drag your dialog this will do the job

```
jQuery('.myDialog').bind('move', function(e) {
    $('#OkButton').focus();
}).bind('moveend', function() {});
```

and when you click on your dialog main div this will do the job.

```
jQuery('.myDialog').click(function(){
    $('#OkButton').focus();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Your first suggestion is maybe better implemented by defining a dragStop event handler on the Diaolog Widget.

Your second suggestion does not work, but this one does
 
`jQuery('.ui-dialog').click(function(){
   $('#okButton').focus();
   return true;
}`

Comment: Thanks for reviewing. and by "mydialog" class i actually meant the main div class which in case of jQuery dialog box is jQuery native ".ui-dialog"